# Cannot start two instances of Microservice using package @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq

Tags: nestjs

I would build a publish/subscribe message pattern between microservices using nestjs and rabbitmq. The problem with the built-in NestJS microservices Rabbitmq does not support pub/sub pattern,but it's easy to start multiple instances of microservice to test random queue message. And i tried to use @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq to implement the features. The problem with this package is that it seem like the port 3000 is the default using by the package and I don't know where and how I could change the port. I couldn't start multiple instances of consummers to test the pattern.

```
 // Module Subcriber 
    import { RabbitMQModule } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { SomeEventConsumerModule1Module } from './some-event-consumer-module1/some-event-consumer-module1.module';
    
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
          exchanges: [
            {
              name: 'amq.topic',
              type: 'topic', // check out docs for more information on exchange types
            },
          ],
          uri: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672', // default login and password is guest, and listens locally to 5672 port in amqp protocol
          // connectionInitOptions: { wait: false },
          channels: {
            'channel-1': {
              prefetchCount: 15,
              default: true,
            },
            'channel-2': {
              prefetchCount: 2,
            },
          },
        }),
        SomeEventConsumerModule1Module,
        
      ],
    })
    export class EventsModule {}
```

Here is the service of Subscriber to get messesage from publisher.

```
// Service Subscriber
// imports
import { RabbitSubscribe } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConsumeMessage, Channel } from 'amqplib'; // for type safety you will need to install package first
// ... so on

@Injectable()
export class SomeEventConsumerModule1Service {
  constructor() {} // other module services if needs to be injected
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'amq.direct',
    routingKey: 'direct-route-key', // up to you
    queue: 'queueNameToBeConsumed',
    errorHandler: (channel: Channel, msg: ConsumeMessage, error: Error) => {
      console.log(error);
      channel.reject(msg, false); // use error handler, or otherwise app will crush in not intended way
    },
  })
  public async onQueueConsumption(msg: {}, amqpMsg: ConsumeMessage) {
    const eventData = JSON.parse(amqpMsg.content.toString());
    // do something with eventData
    console.log(
      `EventData: ${
        eventData.bookName
      }, successfully consumed!${amqpMsg.content.toString()}`,
    );
  }
  // ... and in the same way
}
```

The here is the code of publisher

```
//app module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'GREETING_SERVICE',
        transport: Transport.RMQ,
        options: {
          urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
          queue: 'queueNameToBeConsumed',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

// App service 
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(@Inject('GREETING_SERVICE') private client: ClientProxy) {}

  
  async testEvent() {
    this.client.emit('book-created', {
      bookName: 'The Way Of Kings',
      author: 'Brandon Sanderson',
    });
  }
}
```

the Error message display when trying to start the second instance

```
ERROR [Server] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3000
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1380:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (node:net:1567:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:85:8)
```

I don't know why the port 3000 is using by the service and how to change the port.
[image]

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this at all? I am currently facing the same issue.